# Left Align \text{} in \aligned{} environment latex

Tags: equations, align

I have generated the following code:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    c(s) &= [x_c(s),y_c(s)]^T \in \mathbb{R}^2, & \text{Centerline}, \\
    i(s) &= [x_{in},y_{in}]^T \in \mathbb{R}^2, & \text{Inner Border}, \\
    o(s) &= [x_{out},y_{out}]^T \in \mathbb{R}^2, & \text{Outer Border}, \\
    \Delta(s) &= o(s)-i(s) \in \mathbb{R}^2, & \text{Lateral Deviation}, \\
    t(s) &= i(s) + \alpha(s)\Delta(s), \quad \alpha \in [0,1] & \text{Trajectory}.
\end{aligned} \label{FrameworkTrajectory}
\end{equation}
```

which leads to:
[image: Output]
The problem is that I want to also align the words in all the \text{}'s based on their first letter (left alignment) instead of right, but I fail miserably when trying to do so.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: as always on this site you are more likely to get any help if you provide a full minimal example that others can copy and test as is. That said use `&&\text` instead.

Comment: Explanation: when you have several alignments the number of `&` per line is `2n-1` where `n` is the number of alignments, so it is `n` alignment `&`'s and n-1 `&` to separate the alignments.

Comment: Thank you very much daleif!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just double the ampersand before `\text`. The environment `align` & Co. always alternate right-aligned/left-aligned columns, so after two `&` like in your code you are in a right-aligned column; you need a further `&` to go into the left-aligned one.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
c(s)      &= [x_c(s),y_c(s)]^T \in \mathbb{R}^2,                     &&\text{Centerline},        \\
i(s)      &= [x_{\mathrm{in}},y_{\mathrm{in}}]^T \in \mathbb{R}^2,   &&\text{Inner Border},      \\
o(s)      &= [x_{\mathrm{out}},y_{\mathrm{out}}]^T \in \mathbb{R}^2, &&\text{Outer Border},      \\
\Delta(s) &= o(s)-i(s) \in \mathbb{R}^2,                             &&\text{Lateral Deviation}, \\
t(s)      &= i(s) + \alpha(s)\Delta(s), \quad \alpha \in [0,1] \quad &&\text{Trajectory}.
\end{aligned} \label{FrameworkTrajectory}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I've taken the liberty of making a small modification: ‘in’ and ‘out’ are not symbols but (abbreviations of) real words so they are customarily written with an upright font in sub/superscripts.

Comment: Thank you very much campa!

Comment: @IHBPP, if answer solve your problem, you can consider to accept it (by clicking on the check mark at the top left side of the answer).

Comment: @Zarko, I will! Thanks for the reminder :).